# CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH has no effect

Tags: gcc, g++

I need to add a non-standard location to the system header search path when compiling. There are several ways to skin this cat - I've since chosen a reasonable alternative that does the trick, but it stills bugs me that adding the non-standard location to CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH does not produce the desired result. Any thoughts on what I've done wrong?

docker image - ubuntu:14.04

```
# env

CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include/
HOSTNAME=a339ddd50d28
TERM=xterm
OLDPWD=/usr/local
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
CPATH=/usr/local/cuda/include
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/include
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include/
PWD=/usr/local/include
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env

# ls /usr/local/cuda/include
...
cuda.h
...

# scons
g++ -o .build/cuda_sample.o -c -std=c++11 -fPIC -Wall -O3 cuda_sample.cpp
.build/cuda_sample.cpp:33:18: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE

For what it's worth, /usr/local/cuda/include symlinks to /usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include

Comment: is `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` actually exported?

Comment: Yes, I exported CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH.